# Accessing property inside non-init methods gives bad access

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I've begun work on a side project, so the codebase is very small, very little that could go wrong. Something strange is happening. In viewDidLoad I initialise an array set as a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * story_array;
```

And fill it with data. This printout is fine:

```
NSLog(@"%@", ((ArticlePreview *)[self.story_array objectAtIndex:0]).article);
```

I have a gesture recognizer:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * openStory = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showStory)];
```

Tapping on it calls a method whose first line is this (i.e. the same NSLog):

```
NSLog(@"%@", ((ArticlePreview *)[self.story_array objectAtIndex:0]).article);
```

But this causes a bad access. Accessing story_array itself is fine (it'll say it has however many ArticlePreview objects inside) but accessing their fields is a no-no.

The story_array is init'ed as follows:

self.story_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: You have not posted the most important lines - how do you actually create and initialize your story_array in viewDidLoad method...

Comment: Ah, thanks. It's a simple [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; I'll add that in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assignment to the fields of the ARticle Preview object were not done properly. I had:

```
someField = someValue;
```

I needed:

```
self.someField = someValue;
```

I still find that a bit crazy, but there you go. Solved.